# Exclude all files that have a particular name in the file from Resharper Code analysis

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

VS 2015 - latest Resharper from website.

I have multiple files such as pain.a.js, pain.b.js, pain.c.js.

I've tried excluding folders and files from the Resharper code analysis but I would like to be able to do it as a mask of sort. So if any file has **pain** in the filename it is excluded from Resharper code-wide analysis. Currently when I start my project it causes it to freeze when Resharper runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]In newer versions of Resharper you can skip third-party code. This is the information passed to me by one of the R# developers.

Resharper -> Code Inspection -> Generated Code

Answer (score 0):

In the options under Code **Inspection -> Settings -> File masks** you should be able to set any string and use the wildcard * at the beginning and end to match any filename with that string.

I just tried it in a solution using ***service*** and ReSharper promptly stopped analyzing the ResultService.cs file I had open.

Comment: Ok I was trying pain*. Just tried *pain* and I'm not sure if it works or not as there are still some files being analysed by the Resharper code-analysis (you can bring that up by right-clicking on the processing files).

Comment: JARRRRG, do you have the solution wide analysis turned on? I've never seen a large solution ever use that as it puts so much stress on the system.

Comment: yeah, it was turned on.

Comment: I don't know much about how Soultion wide analysis interacts with such things. Generally I'd recommened turning it off and just fixing classes one by one as you come across them.  Any solution wide stuff like that is best left to CI and Nightly builds where you don't mind if it takes ages.

Comment: I don't know what to do now, I've made a post on the resharper forum too. Hopefully they come up with a better solution. https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205973804-Code-Analysis-not-excluding-files-based-on-filemask